# python PIL using Photoshop to open Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to open image with normal photo viewer but PIL module always opens up Photoshop to show image.

```
from PIL import Image
image1 = Image.open("images/dog_1.jpg")
image1.show()
```

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your default image viewer is set to Photoshop. Try changing to another app in your system settings. If you are on windows 10, then navigate to Settings > Apps > Default apps and change 'Photo viewer' app to the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use openCV instead.

```
import cv2
imagepath = 'images/dog_1.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(imagepath)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
```